# matlab coder requirements stricter than normal matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-coder

Consider the following matlab program:

```
function results = prog()
    opts.x = 1;
    if ~isfield(opts, 'y'); opts.y = 1; end
    'asdf'
return
```

I am able to run this program successfully in matlab however when I try to use coder to convert it to C I get the following error:

```
This structure does not have a field 'y'; new fields cannot be added when structure has been read or used.
```

I would like to know if there is a way to convert to C using coder (or possible some other tool) that does not use a stricter compiler as seems to be the case with coder as I am using it. I am using matlab version R2019B.

Please note that this is just one of many examples of how coder is using a stricter compiler than normal matlab. I have a fairly large program that I would like to convert to C and I don't want to have to go through each error (there are over 100).

Comment: There is no alternative which could translate above code. Structs with optional components are something you can't really translate to C.

Comment: The other alternative is the MATLAB Compiler, which doesn’t translate to C but allows you to run your code without having MATLAB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Daniel mentioned, optional fields of structs don't exist in C, which is why MATLAB Coder errors on that code.

To make this code work with MATLAB Coder, `opts` could always have property `y`, but make it variable-sized and initialized to empty:

```
function results = prog()
    opts.x = 1;
    opts.y = [];
    coder.varsize('opts.y');
    if isempty(opts.y); opts.y = 1; end
    'asdf'
end
```

Or you could create another options variable `optsWithY` that will have field `y`, even if `opts` doesn't:

```
function results = prog()
    opts.x = 1;
    optsWithY = opts;
    if ~isfield(opts, 'y'); optsWithY.y = 1; end
    'asdf'
end
```

This could even be moved into a helper function and assigned back to `opts`:

```
function results = prog()
    opts.x = 1;
    opts = addOpt(opts, 'y', 1);
    'asdf'
end

function newOpts = addOpt(opts, field, defaultValue)
    newOpts = opts;
    if ~isfield(opts, field)
        newOpts.(field) = defaultValue;
    end
end
```

The difference between this and the original code is partial assignment `opts.y = ...` vs complete assignment `opts = ...`.

Or like Cris mentioned, MATLAB Compiler will be a lot closer to MATLAB (though you won't get C code)